# How to use RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have never used requireJS or anything of its like before, and am finding a lack of beginner level tutorials.  I started off by adding the following

```
<script src="/common/lib/require.js" data-main="/common/js/app"></script>
```

which loads require.js and tells it to also initialize itself with the "app.js" file as I understand it.

Inside of app.js I have the following

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'common/js',
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/lib/jquery"
    }
});

define([ 'jquery' ], function( $ ){

});
```

And inside the test page that I am trying to see if it successfully loaded jquery

```
<script>
requirejs(['jquery'], function( $ ) {
    console.log( $ ) ;
});
</script>
```

This causes the web server to simply not find the jquery file. It appears to be looking for /common/js/jquery.js despite my path definition inside of app.js So clearly I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic here; I've edited your question so that it's answerable.

Comment: Ok, you just completely changed your question which pretty much makes my answer irrelevant.

Comment: Overall the question remains the same... ie I do not understand the proper way to use requireJS to include jquery and henceforth use it in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33640233/2):

The point of RequireJS is that you can modularize your app. That basically means that you define what modules you need in the same place where you use them.

```
define([ '/common/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' ], function( $ ){

});
```

In the above code you are telling RequireJS to load jQuery, and when it has been loaded, execute the callback function with the base jQuery function as the callback's first parameter. jQuery is now available *only* inside that function. So you'll have to combine the two files you have now:

```
define([ '/common/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' ], function( $ ){
    $(function(){
        console.log('working');
    });    
});
```

---

### Answer to the current question:

From the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main):

> Note: the script tag require.js generates for your data-main module includes the async attribute. This means that **you cannot assume that the load and execution of your data-main script will finish prior to other scripts referenced later in the same page.**

In other words the browser loads the test page before it has loaded the app.js script, so you can't use RequireJS inside `<script>` tags in the HTML page. If you use RequireJS you'll have to use it for everything.

Your code is otherwise fine, but you'll have to move the test code from the HTML into its own JavaScript file (e.g. "test.js") and run it from the app.js:

```
requirejs(["test.js"], function() {});
```

Comment: How do you go about simply having 'jquery' available and then having other js files require it as needed?  Am I using define when I should be using require?

Comment: I've revised the answer.